# uwsgi + nginx + pypy web service benchmark

Tags: python, web-services, nginx, benchmarking, pypy

What is the best way of to benchmark simple python web service deployed with uwsgi nginx and pypy ?

How can i learn expected average result according to my hardware spesification ?

I used ab:

```
root@# ab -kc 10 -n 1000 http://domain:8080/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking domain (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        domain
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   21.567 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      55000 bytes
HTML transferred:       11000 bytes
Requests per second:    46.37 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       215.673 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       21.567 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2.49 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      103  109  63.1    104    1107
Processing:   103  105   1.6    105     109
Waiting:      103  105   1.6    105     109
Total:        206  214  63.2    209    1215

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    209
  66%    210
  75%    210
  80%    215
  90%    216
  95%    216
  98%    216
  99%    216
 100%   1215 (longest request)
```

But I don't know whether these values ​​are normally or not. It seems very very slow to me. 46 rps with only 10 concurrent connections ?

when i use 100 concurrent connection, my web server crashes and not responding

Where did i go wrong ?

When i used with  1000 concurrent connection, ab can not finish test.

```
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 9894 requests completed
```

Started uwsgi in virtal env:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file foobar.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats :9191
```

My hw: 
     2gb ram, 2 core (linode 2gb)

Answer (score 1):

New here, but I'm going to try to help. The numbers you're seeing are normal, and I don't think you've misconfigured anything necessarily. 10 concurrent connections means that the benchmark is having ten concurrent threads make requests at the same time. The request/second rate that you're seeing is in fact the number of requests being received, and not the rate of your server's responses.

To understand the speed of your server, you should look at the "Time per request", which is the response time. This is the time it takes for one concurrently connected thread to make a request and receive the full response. In this case, 215ms is a good average. The breakdown below is especially helpful, as it shows you that 90% of requests were handled under 216ms, which is close to your average, and shows that the speed of your server's responses is fairly constant. Try to increase the number of concurrent processes or the number of requests that each process sends. That will increase your request/second value, and will push your server harder. Then you can gauge what kind of response time you should expect with a certain number of requests per second (real time traffic load).

Hope this helps!

Comment: when i used with 1000 concurrent connections, ab couldn't finish test: 
Completed 9000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 9894 requests completed

Comment: @MatandDie, this issue seems to be related more directly to the way the uWSGI communicates with nginx. Did you try increasing your buffer-size? If you are receiving large requests, or many requests, you can increase the buffer size to something like 64k in uWSGI with `buffer-size=65535`.

Comment: same result with buffer size parameter. By the way thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 104 error is returned by nginx. This just means that the connection is being forcibly closed. Have you checked your uWSGI logs? They may indicate something like a 502: Bad Gateway that is the real cause of the problem. See a similar question (but with PHP) here: http://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon

Comment: Do the numbers remain stable beyond 1000?  It may be the case that PyPy is still warming up, so try also with 3000 or 5000, just to see.  Also, maybe try with only one thread per process.